# jQuery waypoint function

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm new to jQuery, and I don't know how to do much.

I have the [jQuery waypoint plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) and I also have a function that animates a progress bar. What I need to do is animate the progress bar when a waypoint is reached. I have both pieces of code, but cant seem to put them together.

I need to put this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
            .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 1200);
    });
});
```

Inside of this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#skills-1').waypoint(function() {
        (function here)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#skills-1').waypoint(function() {
        $(".meter > span").each(function() {
            $(this)
                .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
                .width(0)
                .animate({
                    width: $(this).data("origWidth")
            }, 1200);
        });
    });
});
```

Just put it inside, without the function wrapper.

Or if you have multiple waypoints, it's better to make a separate function, like this:

```
function animateProgressBar(){
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
            .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 1200);
    });
}
$('#skills-1').waypoint(animateProgressBar);
$('#skills-2').waypoint(animateProgressBar);
```

Comment: I like the second solution, because I will probably have multiple waypoints, but upon implementing it, I see that the animateProgressBar function runs when the page loads, and not when the first waypoint is reached. Any ideas on how to stop it from running until it's supposed to.

Comment: It shouldn't run until it's called...
Maybe your waypoints are incorrectly set?